# Selenium Webdriver in C#. Control Key is not released

Tags: c#, selenium

I encountered some weird behavior with Selenium Webdriver in C#. In my scenario I need to open image in new tab, make some manipulation with the image and to close the tab. It looks like that for some reason the Control key is not released after the tab is closed (i.e. the browser opens links in new tab on click and it changes the page scale when I'm trying to scroll with mouse wheel). Here is the code:

```
 var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("mainImage"));
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.ContextClick(element).
     SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown).
     SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown).
     SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.ArrowDown).
     SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Return).Build().Perform();
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t");
 string imglink = "";
 if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
 {
     imglink = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text).ToString();
 }
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(imglink);
 var img1name = takeScreenshot(link, brandJoined);
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "w");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Keys.Control` only toggles the state of the control button. So try using:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).
    SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "t" + OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control);
```

The first one will press the control button, the second call will release it.

Comment: @xakepoc have you tried that everywhere you're using `Keys.Control`? It's unwieldy, so if you miss even one it'll mess everything up.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have 4 places overall where I'm using that. I have a workaround so it doesn't affect my project too much, but still it's kind of weird. I even tried this one action.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control); But it's still pressed. I don't think I'll continue to investigate this, but thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a while ago. I was having the same issue and I found a solution.

This happens because the Alt key and the Ctrl key are both toggle keys

The code below does a key down on the ctrl key then sends t and then releases the ctrl key.

```
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).SendKeys("t").KeyUp(Keys.Control).B‌​uild().Perform();
```